# modify moses.ini for incremental training

Tags: moses

I need to update the following moses.ini to support incremental training, I followed the tutorial and I found that I must add this line in moses.ini file

```
PhraseDictionaryDynSuffixArray source=<path-to-source-corpus> target=<path-to-target-corpus> alignment=<path-to-alignments>
```

but no matter how I put it in moses.ini it just doesn't work and give errors when I try to start mt model

here is how I put it to the moses.ini

```
[ttable-file]
PhraseDictionaryDynSuffixArray source=<path-to-source-corpus> target=<path-to-target-corpus> alignment=<path-to-alignments>
```

then I set the appropriate paths, so can anyone help me with this ? thanks in advance